# Using builder-like functions conditionally

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Assume this situation:

I have a `Tuple` of size **n**.
Each element is a `Boolean` flag that defines if a specific function should be called on an object (here: `builder`).

The syntax that comes to my mind first would be:

```
(el1, el2, el3, ...) => {
   val builder = MyBuilder()

   val builder1 = if(el1) builder.func1(...) else builder
   val builder2 = if(el2) builder1.func2(...) else builder1
   val builder3 = if(el3) builder2.func3(...) else builder2
   ...
}
```

The last builder `builderN` would be the desired object. But this code is nasty.

What would be a good, clean alternative? (Note: I am using `cats`.)

Another way to represent my problem would be:

```
val result = MyBuilder.
   .func1(...) //ONLY if el1!
   .func2(...) //ONLY if el2!
   .func3(...) //ONLY if el3!
   ....
   .funcn(...) //ONLY if el4!
```

**EDIT : Fixed example code!**

Comment: I believe the issue is in the initial assumption that your input should be a tuple of flags telling whether a function should be applied to some input. This is already a code smell, and won't lead to a good functional solution. Perhaps you could share the actual problem you're trying to solve, and we can propose a different design.

Comment: It's the result of using this typesafe-approved library: https://github.com/bkirwi/decline . See the use of `mapN` in the first example in the README file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can zip list of flags with list of building functions and then in the fold conditionally apply builder function

```
class Builder() {

  def func1(in: Any): Builder = {
    println("func1")
    this
  }

  def func2(in: Any): Builder = {
    println("func2")
    this
  }

  def func3(in: Any): Builder = {
    println("func3")
    this
  }
}

val flags = List(true, false, true)
val funcs = List[Builder => Builder](b => b.func1(1), b => b.func2(2), b => b.func3(3))
val result = flags.zip(funcs).foldLeft(new Builder()) {
  case (builder, (flag, func)) => if (flag) func(builder) else builder
}
```

prints to console:

```
func1
func3
```